# How to hide notification bar of settings intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am making an custom system setting application my goal is user can not see notification bar so i used this code its working fine.

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

[image: User Settings]

but the problem is when i open settings intent from my app it shows notification bar i want to remove notification bar from this intent too how i can do this.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
```

[image: Problem]

my device is rooted i am making my own launcher please guide me how i can do this.
sorry for poor English i tried my best to explain my problem

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing now. Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
i.putExtra(":android:show_fragment", "com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings");
i.putExtra(":android:no_headers", true);

startActivity(i);
```

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing now. Can it be done?